# R: efficient way to store boxplot.stats in data.frame

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I work in R and I have a data from of 143 variables and about 50000 observations. The data is stored as `data.frame` called TR. For each variable I want to store the results of the `boxplot.stats` in one common `data.frame`, which is called Outlier.

My first attempt was a `for`-loop, but I guess there are more efficient ways...

```
    for (n in 1:143) {Outlier[n] <- cbind(boxplot.stats(TR[,n]))}
```

This works, but it is slow and not pretty. It also does not allow me to set `colnames` for some reason.

My output so far is:

```
print(Outlier)
[[1]]
[1]  -5.86250  33.30000  48.19875  71.00750 127.53750

[[2]]
[1]    0.00  150.75  357.25  706.75 1540.75

[[3]]
[1] -11.2900  30.0000  44.9900  59.9900 104.9725
```

and so on up to [[143]]

What I would want is a data frame in which the column names are the same than the column name of the original data set (so the summary of the variable "age" would be called "age" again instead of [111]).

I suppose some form of the `apply`-function should work for me!?

Thanks for the help!

---

EDIT (edited 2 times)

I want to get a data frame in which for each variable (e.g column), the respective stats are computed. The solution proposed before instead gives me the values of the entries which are in the respective whisker positions due to the first column, which is the customer_ID. (THis also brings me to the point that I should probably delete the customer_ID, since its stats are totally irrelevant, of course...)

What I want is:

```
                customer_ID   age  ... 
lower whisker   1             4
lower ‘hinge’                 18
median           25000        45
upper ‘hinge’                 60
upper whisker   500000        89
```

Comment: you can try `lapply(TR,boxplot.stats)`, what stats do you want to keep ? If you want to keep only the first element, you can do: `do.call("cbind",lapply(TR,function(x) boxplot.stats(x)$stats))`

Comment: @CathG, I want to keep all the 5 values.

Comment: there are 4 elements in the result of `boxplot.stats`: `stats`= the 5 "key" values, `n`= the number of non-NA observations, `conf`= the "CI" and `out`= the outliers. If you are just interested in the 5 key values (extreme of the lower whisker, lower ‘hinge’, median, upper ‘hinge’ and extreme of the upper whisker), you can use the method in the answer I posted. (you can see how it works with the example of 10 variables named from "var1" to "var10)

Comment: jep - sorry for the bad formulation. This is exactly what I meant. It works very fine and also got me the `colnames` correctly.  So the trick is to use `lapply` instead of `for` and also specify the `boxplot$stats` instead of just `boxplot`. And my next task is to read up on the `do.call`-function.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to keep only the first element ("stats"), you can do:

```
 do.call("cbind", lapply(TR, function(x) boxplot.stats(x)$stats))
```

**Example:**

```
TR<-data.frame(matrix(rnorm(1000, 0, 1), nrow=100))
colnames(TR) <- paste0("var", 1:10)

result <- do.call("cbind",lapply(TR,function(x) boxplot.stats(x)$stats))
row.names(result) <- c("lower whisker", "lower hinge", "median", "upper hinge", "upper whisker")

> result
#                        var1       var2        var3       var4        var5        var6       var7       var8       var9       var10
# lower whisker  -2.576439995 -2.2792196 -2.35167507 -1.8877539 -2.58913827 -2.16186578 -2.2256634 -2.6224338 -2.6553318 -2.20051934
# lower hinge    -0.702412927 -0.8807600 -0.51379104 -0.8844453 -0.70669242 -0.67969000 -0.4659781 -0.9299630 -0.6832023 -0.75777439
# median         -0.001227173 -0.1061840  0.05179841 -0.1814486  0.07202305 -0.05771931  0.1607952 -0.1093029  0.1497963  0.02718001
# upper hinge     0.713235646  0.6534857  0.86043753  0.5778967  0.60288720  0.35219547  0.7317339  0.5787307  0.7458351  0.78165452
# upper whisker   2.596567487  2.2561072  2.66626361  1.7087384  2.24049360  1.81568251  1.9378385  2.5409711  2.3770803  3.01762144
```

Comment: a closer look at the results I got actually showed me that this is not what I am looking for. It gives me instead the values for the entries at the lower whisker, lower ‘hinge’, median, upper ‘hinge’ and extreme of the upper whisker, going by ID. :( 

What I want instead is to compute those numbers for each variable.

Comment: @PikkuKatja, first, I'm really sorry that I put the row.names too quickly, doing a copy/paste of what you had put in your question (min, 25%...) but actually this did not correspond to the value computed by `boxplot.stats` :-( (which are what I did put in a previous comment...) so this is corrected but again, sorry. Concerning your comment, I don't really understand it because what is computed is actually the different stats for each variable... Could you edit your question with your input data.frame and desired output ?

Comment: hey @CathG, I found out about the whiskers myself and I corrected it in the last edit. Actually, even though it is not exactly the numbers I was looking for, they still proved useful. Hm, if, as you say, the stats are computed for each column respectively, I guess what I need to do is to have a very close look at my data and see where the weird results I get come from. If I still actually have a programming question (and not just a question of mis-formatted data), I will get back to you :-) thank you for you help!